# Can I put multiple statements in a interpolated string in C# 6?

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

In Ruby, I can put multiple statements in a interpolated string, eg.

```
puts "#{a = 1; b = 2; a + b;}"
```

Or I can put them in multiple lines like this:

```
puts "#{a = 1;
b = 2;
a + b;}"
```

Can I do the same thing in C# 6? I've tried but failed. Below is my C# code.

```
Console.WriteLine($@"haha
{int a = 1;
 int b = 2;
 a+b;}
heihei");
```

When I try to run the C# program, I got:

```
CS1525 Invalid expression term 'int'
CS1073 Unexpected token 'a'
```

I hope someone can help.

Comment: You're asking 2 different questions at once...

Comment: I'm not sure I've what you mean. But I think you can simply use @
Like this:
Console.WriteLine($@"haha
{int a = 1;
 int b = 2;
 a+b;}
heihei");

Comment: @i3arnon Looks like one to me. What's the second one?

Comment: @Rob 1. Multiple statements - not possible. 2. Multiline - possible.

Comment: @i3arnon, Haha, thanks. I got it now.

Comment: @user130268 keep in mind though that a multiline string will actually print a multiline string with line breaks and all...

Comment: @i3arnon, Thanks for reminding. I got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have full code blocks in your string interpolation statements. You can only do evaluations inside.

So this works (pulled the variables outside):

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
Console.WriteLine($@"haha
{a+b}
heihei");
```

And this too (do evaluation only):

```
Console.WriteLine($@"haha
{1+2}
heihei");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is different then C# in your case you write full code in your string interpolation so it's not working.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Name = {name}, hours = {hours:hh}")
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine($@"haha {1+2} heihei");
```

For Ref: [Microsoft C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)